# text following the table displays underneath

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://vivesco-mhf.com.au/fitness-classes/), my client has the following HTML
(I understand the client uses extra text editing inside Wordpress, hence the `<span style="foobar">`):

```html
<table id="regulartable" style="height: 339px;" width="1284">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="regularstandard" scope="col"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"> </span></th>
<th class="regularstandard" scope="col"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #ff9900; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">MON</span></strong></th>
<th class="regularstandard" scope="col"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #ff9900; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">TUE</span></strong></th>
<th class="regularstandard" scope="col"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #ff9900; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">WED</span></strong></th>
<th class="regularstandard" scope="col"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #ff9900; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">THUR</span></strong></th>
<th class="regularstandard" scope="col"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #ff9900; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">FRI</span></strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="regulartable-highlight-odd"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">09.30am</span></strong></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Cardio Punch<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Picnic Cove Park<br />
Edgewater</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Fun and Games<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Eiffel Circuit<br />
Tapping<br />
</span></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Cardio Punch<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Frederick Duffy Park<br />
Wanneroo</span></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">FBI &#8211; A<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Nankeen Circuit<br />
Tapping</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Fun n Games<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Picnic Cove Park<br />
Edgewater</span><br />
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="regulartable-highlight-odd"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">10.30am</span></strong></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">FBI &#8211; A<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Eiffel Circuit<br />
Tapping</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">FBI &#8211; A<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Frederick Duffy Park<br />
Wanneroo</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="regulartable-highlight-odd"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">02.00pm</span></strong></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">FBI &#8211; A<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Picnic Cove Park<br />
Edgewater</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Cardio Punch<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Frederick Duffy Park<br />
Wanneroo</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211; </span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="regulartable-highlight-odd"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">06.00pm</span></strong></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Cardio Punch<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Picnic Cove Park<br />
Edgewater</span><br />
</span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Fun n Games<br />
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Nankeen Circuit<br />
Tapping</span></span></td>
<td class="regulartable-odd"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">&#8211;</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clearsmall" style="text-align: right;"><span style="color: #000000;"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Sessions usually run for 1 hour  </span>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #ff9900; text-decoration: underline;"> <a href="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/classic/ws?studioid=262803&amp;stype=41&amp;sTG=22" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 'https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/classic/ws?studioid=262803&amp;stype=41&amp;sTG=22', 'Pricing and Booking');" class="calloutaction" style="color: #ff9900; text-decoration: underline;">Pricing and Booking</a> </span></span></strong></span></div>
<hr />
<h3 style="text-align: justify;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; color: #cc99ff;">Fun and Games</span></strong></h3>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Working a sweat whilst having fun playing games! Challenge yourself, encourage your team mates, get your body pumping, and maybe&#8230;maybe meet your younger self again <img src="http://vivesco-mhf.com.au/wp-includes/images/smilies/simple-smile.png" alt=":-)" class="wp-smiley" style="height: 1em; max-height: 1em;" /></span></p>
<hr />
<h3 style="text-align: justify;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; color: #cc99ff;">Full Body Integrated Awesomeness  (FBI &#8211; A)</span></strong></h3>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">A session all about you! Exercising for strength, for cardio, for mobility, for recovery = for a feeling of AWESOMENESS!</span><br />
<span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"> Using ViPR, Sandbells, and Bodyweight, every single exercise is fully customizable to suit you!<br />
</span></p>
<hr />
<h3 style="text-align: justify;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; color: #cc99ff;">Cardio Punch</span></strong></h3>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">A session involving a lot of punching, some kicking, and getting your heart pumping.</span><br />
<span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"> Gloves and Mitts provided, but feel free to bring your own if you prefer.</span></p>
<hr />
<h3><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; color: #cc99ff;">Sand Running   <span style="color: #ff0000;">Currently not scheduled</span></span></strong></h3>
<p><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">Self explanatory: We will go for run training on the beach. This is for beginners which means the training is interval based and can be customized where needed</span></p>
<hr />
<h3 style="text-align: justify;"><span style="color: #000000; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">These sessions are limited to 10 participants, so bookings are essential.</span></h3>
<hr />
```

When the view port is 525px wide or smaller, the `table#regulartable` ("group schedule") changes to a responsive table based on [this project](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

However, the `<div class="clear"></div>` at the end of `table#regulartable` does not seem to work, as the text following the `table#regulartable` displays underneath `table#regulartable`:

[image]

This is taken from Mozilla Firefox responsive view.

How can I get the text starting from "Sessions usually run for 1 hour..." to display after the `table#regulartable`, and not peaking through it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't clearing, but the height definition on regulartable (339px). Removing it makes the responsive view look fine.